# Hamcrest matcher with slashes is interpreted as a part of validation

Tags: java, hamcrest, rest-assured

I have the following validation where I have to check if returned body has a string containing `"id": 6354`, but it interprets slashes of special characters. How I can validate strings which contain double quotation marks ?

**Code**

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.containsString;
import com.jayway.restassured.response.Response;


    response.then()
            .body(containsString("\"id\": 6354"));
```

**Error**

```
Response body doesn't match expectation.
Expected: a string containing "\"id\": 6354"
  Actual: {...,"id": 6354, ...}
```

Comment: What's the code of `containsString`?

Comment: @NiklasP I've updated the question,

Comment: Could you provide an example of the JSON document?

Comment: How did you fix this? Got the same problem

Answer (score 3):

Hamcrest containsString seems to print the escaped characters in the output error message, however it seems to correctly escape them when doing the matching.

In my example, I was incorrectly adding a space, so following the example in the question: 
`"id": 6354` would give the error `Expected: a string containing "\"id\": 6354"` however when I changed it to `"id":6354"`, it passed the assertion.

Comment: I experience the same behavior here with the actual matching working correctly even though the output error message prints the escape characters; as a reference I am using Hamcrest 1.3.  Perhaps this behavior is different in a newer version?

Answer (score 2):

I think there is something wrong with the escape slash. So I used:

```
assertTrue(response.contains("\"id\":6354"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar seemingly perplexing problem, but the solution was simple. I was comparing a non-String object with a String therefore it failed. The confusion comes in because the description of non-String object looks like a String without the escape characters.

To solve the problem, I changed:

```
assertThat(message, is(expectedLog));
```

to:

```
assertThat(message.toString(), is(expectedLog));
```